# How to obtain the resolved version (static version) from of a dependency with a dynamic version programmatically in build.gradle?

Tags: gradle

Using gradle, I have a dependency declared with a dynamic version

```
ext {
    fooLibVersion = [1.0.0, 1.0.999]   
}
dependencies {
    implementation "org.examble:foo-lib:$fooLibVersion"
}
```

Now I want to create my project's javadoc with links to the `lib-foo` javadoc, for this I have

```
javadoc {
    …
    options {
        links = [
            "https://example.org/foo-lib/releases/$fooLibVersion/javadoc/"
        ]
    }
}
```

However this will, of course, fail with

```
javadoc: error - Malformed URL: https://example.org/foo-lib/releases/[1.0.0, 1.0.999]/javadoc/
```

How can I programmatically obtain the resolved version, IINM also called "static version", of `foo-lib` (which was declared with a dynamic version), and use it in the variable part of the javadoc link argument?

Answer (score 0):

Gradle doesn't appear to offer a clean way to do this out of the box. For example (Kotlin DSL), getting a reference to the actual dependency does not yield the resolved version:

```
val commonsLangVersion by extra { listOf("3.9", "3.10") }

dependencies {
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:$commonsLangVersion")
}

configurations.compileClasspath.get().allDependencies.find { it.name == "commons-lang3" }?.let {
    println(it)
}
```

Results in:

```
$ ./gradlew build

> Configure project :
DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='org.apache.commons', name='commons-lang3', version='[3.9, 3.10]', configuration='default'}
```

So the only way to get the actual version is to resolve the configuration, then perform some substring manipulation based on the filename:

```
val commonsLangVersion by extra { listOf("3.9", "3.10") }

dependencies {
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:$commonsLangVersion")
}

val resolvedVersion = configurations.compileClasspath.get().resolve()
        .filter { it.name.startsWith("commons-lang3") }[0] // commons-lang3-3.10.jar
        .name.substringAfterLast("-") // 3.10.jar
        .substringBeforeLast(".") // 3.10

println(resolvedVersion)

tasks.javadoc {
    options {
        (this as StandardJavadocDocletOptions)
        links = listOf(
                "https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-$resolvedVersion/"
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should resolve artifact, look at following code :

```
task myDepList {
    doLast {
        subprojects.each { subproject ->
            println "Project : ${subproject.name}"
            subproject.configurations.each { configuration -> 
                println "Configuration : ${subproject.name}#${configuration.name}"
                    if (configuration.canBeResolved) {
                        configuration.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each { ra -> 
                            println "Resolved : ${subproject.name}#${ra.moduleVersion.id.group}:${ra.moduleVersion.id.name}:${ra.moduleVersion.id.version}"
                        }
                    }
                    configuration.allDependencies.each { dependency -> 
                        def type = []
                        if (dependency instanceof ExternalDependency) {
                            type.add "ExternalDependency"
                        }
                        if (dependency instanceof ClientModule) {
                            type.add "ClientModule"
                        }
                        if (dependency instanceof ExternalModuleDependency) {
                            type.add "ExternalModuleDependency"
                        }
                        if (dependency instanceof FileCollectionDependency) {
                            type.add "FileCollectionDependency"
                        }
                        if (dependency instanceof ModuleDependency) {
                            type.add "ModuleDependency"
                        }
                        if (dependency instanceof ProjectDependency) {
                            type.add "ProjectDependency"
                        }
                        if (dependency instanceof SelfResolvingDependency) {
                            type.add "SelfResolvingDependency"
                        }
                        println "Dependency ${type}: ${subproject.name}#${configuration.name}#${dependency.group}:${dependency.name}:${dependency.version}"
                        if (dependency instanceof ModuleDependency) {
                            dependency.artifacts.each { artifact -> 
                                println "        Artifact ${artifact.name}:${artifact.type}:${artifact.classifier}:${artifact.extension} => ${artifact.url}"
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```